# Why won't my component be recognized when trying to import?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, debugging

I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't let me import my `<Login/>` component in my `<Main/>` component.  I'm pretty sure my directory path's written correctly (or is it?) which's why it's strange to me that this isn't working.

I tried running `npm install --save ./resources/js/components/Login`
 but that didn't work.

This is a Laravel project but I'm using React for frontend.  Attached is an image of my working directory.  How can I fix my problem?

Here's `Main.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './resources/js/components/Login';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1 className="text-center">test</h1>
            <Login/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('example'));
}

export default Main;
```

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="emailInput">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="passwordInput">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Here's `login.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        @include('partials.metadata')

        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" type="text/css">


    </head>
    <body>
    <main id="example">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            {{-- JSX --}}
        </div>
    </main>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/containers/Main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: did you export the `Login` component ? Can you show us the code of `Login.js` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé posted

Comment: it seems to be ok, where is the file `Main.js` in your working directory ?

Comment: where is main.js in the directory structure?

Comment: @ManavM I just posted my login.blade.php file.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Is my login.blade.php file off?  I just posted it.

Comment: what we want to know is where the file `Main.js` is placed in your directory struture ? I think the problem comes from this line `import Login from './resources/js/components/Login';`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé ah ok!  It's inside the containers folder.  sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @OlivierBoissé wait I got it!! it's supposed to be `import Login from '../../js/components/Login';`.  it works now!

Comment: `import Login from '../components/Login'` should work too

Comment: @OlivierBoissé whoa that's strange!  how come it works both ways?

Comment: both relatives path point to the same destination.

Comment: when you use something like `../components/Login` it is a relative path which is calculated from the directory in which the file is defined, that is, from the containers folder. You can also give an absolute path like `resources/js/components/Login`...Note the lack of `.`.